# ¿Como solucionar error non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase `Animal` como sigue

```
class Animal {
    protected double peso;
    protected double altura;
    Alimento AlimsIngeridos[];
    
    public Animal (double peso, double altura){
        this.peso = peso;
        this.altura= altura;
    }
    public double getPeso(){
      return peso;
  }
    public double getAltura(){
      return altura;
  }

     public double getAlimsIngeridos(){
       /*implmentacion*/
   }
  }
```

Ahora se necesita crear una clase `Gorila` que herede de la clase `Animal` y que tenga un metodo llamado `getIMC`,pero me sale error "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" al intentar llamar los metodos `getPeso` y `getAltura`, ¿Como puedo solucionar ese error?

```
class Gorila extends Animal {
  public Gorila (double peso, double altura){
      super(peso,altura);
  }
    
  public static double getPesoAlims(){
    /*implementacion*/
  }
  
  public double getIMC(){      
      double IMC = (Gorila.getPesoAlims()/1000 + Gorila.getPeso())/(Gorila.getAltura()*Gorila.getAltura());       
      return (Math.floor(IMC));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema esta en la forma en la que estas haciendo referencia a los métodos de la clase Gorila dentro del método getIMC(), deberías referenciarlos sin el nombre de la clase Gorila adelante ya que son funciones internas de esta clase, de esta forma:

```
 public double getIMC(){      
      double IMC = (getPesoAlims()/1000 + getPeso())/(getAltura()*getAltura());       
      return (Math.floor(IMC)); 
     }
```